# Python 3.3.2 with Shared option is incomplete

Tags: software-installation, compiling, shared-library, python3

On Ubuntu 12.04, I am trying to compile and install Python3.3.2. My compile commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared
make
make install
```

Then I run:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.3 --version
```

and get:

```
python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.3m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I build without --enable-shared, everything runs fine, but I need the shared option to compile mod_wsgi against it.

I do find libpython3.3m.so.1.0 in the /usr/local/lib folder, so I wonder if it is just looking in the wrong place.  Do I need to do a symlink from somewhere?

Comment: Close voters, this is a XY situation, OP wants `mod_wsgi` and tries to compile it himself instead installing the Ubuntu package that is already compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you want to build mod_wsgi using the sources, but isn't more easier installing the deb packages?

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

or if you want python 3 version:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

`apt-cache show libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`:

> Python 3 WSGI adapter module for Apache
>    The mod_wsgi adapter is an Apache module that provides a WSGI (Web Server
>    Gateway Interface, a standard interface between web server software and
>    web applications written in Python) compliant interface for hosting Python
>    based web applications within Apache. The adapter provides significantly
>    better performance than using existing WSGI adapters for mod_python or CGI.
>    This package provides a module for Python 3.X.

Comment: So compile without --enable-shared and just use these?  They work with python3.3?

Comment: You don't need to compile anything, is already compiled for you to use.

Comment: I mean compiling Python 3.3, because that's what was giving me the errors.  Since I can use apt-get for the mod-wsgi, is there any reason to keep the --enable-shared on the Python 3.3 compilation?

Comment: You don't need to compile python, you already will have mod-wsgi which is your final propose. You can delete the compiled python for all I can know.

Comment: Alright, thanks man!  I'll try to get a new VM fired up next week and give it a shot.