# enable shared libraries for python

Tags: 16.04, server, python, postgresql, shared-library

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL with PL/Python server programming language on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I run `./configure --with-python`, I receive an error/warning asking for a shared python library. The PostgreSQL documentation knows that Ubuntu does not have this library shared by default, but doesn't provide info on how to set it up to work.

I tried installing python from source with `./configure --enable-shared`, but when I try to run python I get an error loading my shared library. I don't remember the exact error message because I reset the server I was working on, but it was similar to the error encountered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348053/python-3-3-2-with-shared-option-is-incomplete). I can replicate the problem and get the exact error message if need be.

My question is: how do I properly setup my python shared library for my PostgreSQL installation to work?

Comment: *" The PostgreSQL documentation knows that Ubuntu does not have this library shared by default"* huh? `libpython-dev` should install both the static and shared libpython2.x libraries AFAIK

Comment: I misunderstood the comment in the documentation, they said it's not the default when _compiling from source_, my mistake. You could be right.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. So (assuming you have installed `libpython-dev`) what is the exact error when you run `./configure --with-python`?

Comment: I wanted to use python3 so I installed `libpython3-dev`, the `./configure --with-python` output asked for a couple more packages. I installed them and I have no errors. Thank you.